# Cucumber Testing Race Condition Jenkins Run On Concurrent Servers

Tags: jenkins, cucumber

I have a Cucumber test suite which is executed by Jenkins on a pool of servers that at times is run concurrently across the server pool.

I am experiencing a race condition when database stored settings are altered by the test run on server A which then causes the test run on server B to fail because its looking for the settings to be in a different state

Is there a way to configure cucumber tests or Jenkins to have the scenario running on server B wait for the scenario running on server A to complete before it may proceed?

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to not have your tests depend on each other; each test should be able to pass individually. So the best solution would be to redesign your tests so they they do no depend on the db to be in a certain state, or at least for the state of one test not to interfere with another.

Comment: To confirm, my tests are not depending on each other.  The problem is that my test is being executed on server A and server B at the same time due to developers committing changes that get executed by Jenkins in the server pool.

Comment: Your tests both depend on something being in a particular state and this state is manipulated by your tests. You tests are not independent.